# Building Apache 2.2 from source on CentOS

Tags: shell, centos, apache-httpd, php

**My Question**

Does anyone have a link to a proper source package of Apache 2.2 for CentOS, and if so are there any special instructions I'm missing ?

**Summary**

I am trying to install Apache 2.2 on a AWS Linux AMI, The specific AMI ID is below:

```
Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0d1000aff9a9bad89
```

Since yum does not support anything before Apache 2.4, I need to download my 2.2 version from the Apache website and build it from source.

I also know that since I'm running CentOS I should be installing the 'httpd' version instead of 'apache2'

**Part 1: Installing httpd with yum works, but only for Apache 2.4**

If I do:

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

Everything installs as I would expect:

- /var/www/html directory is created
- /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf is
- created  I can run 'sudo service start httpd'
- I am able to deploy my application
- However, it installs Apache 2.4

**Part 2: Download Apache 2.2 and building from source does not work as I'd expect**

Since I have this requirement that I must run a 2.2 version of Apache, I download it to the instance and build from source using the commands below:

```
sudo wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz
tar -zxf httpd-2.2.29.tar.gz
./configure
Make 
sudo Make install
```

After I run the above commands and build from source:

- There is no /var/www/html directory created
- There is no /etc/httpd directory created
- I get the message below:

> 'Failed to start httpd.service: Unit not found.'

when running 'sudo service httpd start'

*Side Note:* I am aware I can copy things around and manually alter the conf file, the reason I believe something is awry is because I cannot run 'httpd' commands with the 2.2 version.

Comment: You compiled it from source. There isn't going to be a `/var/www/html` or an `/etc/httpd` directory nor will there be a service. The `www` directory and the config directory and files are going to be inside of the directory where you compiled it. You'll need to create a service for it so that you can start it with `systemd` and you'll have to add the directory containing the executables to your `$PATH`. What you are looking for is only provided if you install it the package with either `yum` or `rpm`.

Answer (score 0):

1.
There is no /var/www/html directory created
There is no /etc/httpd directory created

Manually create these two directories and assign proper permission and owner/group

2.Failed to start httpd.service: Unit not found when running 'sudo service httpd start'

Missing service file in /usr/lib/systemd/system
Create httpd.service and edit the content from systemd [documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/understanding-and-administering-systemd/index.html) and softlink the file to /etc/systemd/system by enable the service

```
# systemctl enable httpd.service
# systemctl start httpd.service
```